# Where does the Kettenkrad engine come from?

Tags: charles-stross, laundry-files

In *The Atrocity Archives*, part of the *Laundry Files* series by Charles Stross, the protagonist, Bob Howard finds a Kettenkrad on the other end of a portal.

> Some kind of small vehicle, like a weird cross between a tank and a motorbike, is parked against the wall, dusty with a sprinkling that isn't snow.

Some time later, it's gone.

> (...) the little half-track thing with a motorcycle's front wheel is missing.

But when

> Bob gets home, there's a Kettenkrad engine on his kitchen table.
>
> > The front hall is full of petite tank tracks. They're about twenty centimetres wide, covered in dried-up mud, and run past the hulking Victorian coat rack and the living room door to stop just short of the kitchen.
> >
> > (...)
> >
> > There's most of an engine block on the kitchen table.
>
> Later it's confirmed that this is the engine block of a Kettenkrad, belonging to one of Bob's housemates.

**Where does it come from?**

---

*Reading back, I think I just read too much into the missing and resurfacing Kettenkrad, excluding the possibility that it's just a weird coincidence. Also, I thought Morris to be one of the casualties.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implication is that the soldier Morris took it as a souvenir.

> "Cool, I always wanted a Kettenkrad," someone remarks on the common
>   channel.
>
> "Morris, shut the fuck up; the cylinder heads are probably vacuum
>   welded anyway. Chaitin, check out the doors. Scary Spice, cover with
>   the M40."

then

> Someone's parked that electric trolley next to the wall, but the
>   little half-track thing with a motorcycle's front wheel is missing.
>   "Someone taking souvenirs?" I ask.
>
> A burst of static that I just about decode as "What?" tells me that
>   the interference is worse than before; I glance up and see red stars,
>   a dull red swirl of galaxy overhead . . . a distinct pink tinge to the
>   moon, in fact.
>
> I point at where the Kettenkrad was parked. "There, it's gone," I say.
>   "Who took it?"
>
> Chaitin shrugs.

Since Brains is a member of the same organisation as Bob, and something of a mechanical wizard (although not literally), he's clearly been given the engine to fix by the light-fingered soldier...